# stretch a background-image across a table's td using html/css

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, stretch

I have a table and want a certain background to be stretched across the width of the TD, whatever the width may be.

My CSS for the relevant `td` is currently like this:

```
.tools .theader
{
margin:1px;background-color:#ffffcc;
background:url(../images/td_bg.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

and the HTML goes something like this:

```
<table class'tools'>
<tr>
<td class='theader' colspan=2>
Background
</td>
...
```

Here's an image of what I get in result:
[image]

So you can see the blue bevelled background fits exactly in the center of each `td`. I want it to stretch to reach the edges of the `td` so that the whole `td` looks bevelled. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css gradient instead

**HTML**

```
<table class'tools'>
<tr>
<td class='theader' colspan="2">
    <span>Background</span>
</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
.theader > span{
    color:white;
    padding:6px 10px;
    background: #fffcfc; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fffcfc 0%, #2989d8 12%, #2989d8 51%, #207cca 96%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fffcfc), color-stop(12%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#2989d8), color-stop(96%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fffcfc 0%,#2989d8 12%,#2989d8 51%,#207cca 96%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fffcfc 0%,#2989d8 12%,#2989d8 51%,#207cca 96%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fffcfc 0%,#2989d8 12%,#2989d8 51%,#207cca 96%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fffcfc 0%,#2989d8 12%,#2989d8 51%,#207cca 96%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fffcfc', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gn75n/2/)

**[HERE](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)** is the best tool to generate CSS Gradient